# More help required on custom graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, css

I've asked a question on here before on bulding a custom pie chart and have not had any luck on that. I'm back again for help on another graph as I don't know how to approach building it.

The learning curve for javascript/jquery is steep for me so asking questions help. Here is a link to what the design looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEwI0.jpg

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Could you post some code, show us what you have tried so far :-)

Comment: At the moment I'm just looking for a proper solution. The 'probable' solution that I've come up with so far will make you laugh but here goes nothing. The chart as it is will never change in range so there are only a set number of variations on what can be done with one column. So the plan so far is to use images. I would create a div with a blank chart image in it and then a row of divs that are positioned absolutely on top of it. Each div will then call the image associated with the number or I will use a sprite image. It sounds archaic but if I get in a pinch, this is what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work , This is happening because you are using same id="msg" for all the two
1st 2nd  ,  textbox which can't be possible only id with one name can be used in a form 
use classes if you want to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JS libraries like D3.js, Springly.js or arborjs? all these are data visualization libraries which you can use. There are tons of examples, try to find something similar to your requirement and customize it.